# Django custom PasswordResetForm

Tags: django, forms, python-2.7

I am trying to use the PasswordResetForm built-in function.

As I want to have custom form fields, I wrote my own form:

```
class FpasswordForm(PasswordResetForm):
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': 'autofocus'}))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("email")
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if function_checkemaildomain(email) == False:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Untrusted email domain")
        elif function_checkemailstructure(email)==False:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This is not an email adress.")

        return email
```

And here is my view in views.py

```
@cache_control(max_age=0, no_cache=True, no_store=True, must_revalidate=True)
def fpassword(request):
    form = FpasswordForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
        if function_checkemail(email):
            form.save(from_email='blabla@blabla.com', email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html')
            print "EMAIL SENT"
        else:
            print "UNKNOWN EMAIL ADRESS"
```

And my email template is:

```
{% autoescape off %}
You're receiving this e-mail because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.

Please go to the following page and choose a new password:
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url "django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm" uidb36=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}

Your username, in case you've forgotten: {{ user.username }}

Thanks for using our site!

The {{ site_name }} team.

{% endautoescape %}
```

The problem is that I have a `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_host'` error... The traceback log is telling me that in  `current_site = RequestSite(request)` , request is `None`.
Maybe I have something else to add in my `save()` in views.py ?

When I use the following method without custom fields in my form and built-in views, all is working good: http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/django-resetting-passwords-with.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you're getting that error because it's trying to call a method on a instance that's set to `None`. Here's the correct view you should use:

```
@cache_control(max_age=0, no_cache=True, no_store=True, must_revalidate=True)
def fpassword(request):
    form = FpasswordForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
        if function_checkemail(email):
            form.save(from_email='blabla@blabla.com', email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html', request=request)
            print "EMAIL SENT"
        else:
            print "UNKNOWN EMAIL ADRESS"
```

Another option would be to enable the [Django Sites Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework). Then you wouldn't have to pass in request because `get_current_site` would return the site current instance. Here's a [link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9ffab9cee1a5bd1a2f6c326ae970d92526f9a304/django/contrib/sites/shortcuts.py#L6) to that logic.

Comment: you can add the 'domain_override'  kwarg to the save method and it should bypass that error also. As in ```form.save(domain_override="yourdomain.com")```